# Android NDK problems related to stdarg.h

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to make native (C++) cross-platform logging for desktop and Android. For that I made an abstract native Logger class, and the appropriate inherited classes (StdoutLogger, AndroidLogger, etc.) with the implemented log methods.
So since what Android supports for native logging is the __android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag,  const char *fmt, ...) method which works with a printf-like syntax with  indefinite number of arguments, I made the abstract log method to work with a similar syntax:

```
virtual void log(int aLogLevel, const char *tag, const char *format, ...)=0;
```

Well, for passing these indefinite numbers of arguments to the Android logging method I found I need to use another method which does the same but takes a va_list instead of the indefinite number of parameters. It also exists in log.h and is called __android_log_vprint(int prio, const char *tag, const char *fmt, va_list ap), so I just have to pass the arguments for that method instead.

The problem is that for all this to work I need stdarg.h which contains all the stuff I need for this (like the declaration for va_list, etc.), but by default Eclipse can't find it:
Unresolved inclusion:

In Eclipse project settings my include directories include:

```
${NDKROOT}/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
${NDKROOT}/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include
```

It's pretty strange that it's missing, because stdarg.h is part of the C standard library.

So I searched and found it here so I added it to the include directories:

```
${NDKROOT}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include
```

After this I got it working nicely, but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to do it.

Anyway, later (when implementing the log method in another inherited class) I ran into another problem regarding vfprintf method:

```
virtual void Log(int aLogLevel, const char *tag, const char *format, ...)
{
    if (aLogLevel >= loglevel)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start (args, format);
        vfprintf (stdout, format, args);
        va_end (args);
    }
}
```

Eclipse indicated an error:

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: int vfprintf(__sFILE *, const char *, char *) '
```

I checked and apparently it wanted a __va_list (with __ at the beginning), not a va_list and it looked like they apparently weren't compatible (according to Eclipse). This vfprintf was in stdio.h, so I started searching and found another stdio.h in a similar folder I found stdarg.h, so I added it to include directories too (and moved it to top) :

```
${NDKROOT}/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/include-fixed
```

Now all errors are gone and everything seem to be working, but I'm really unsure if this was really the correct way to do it.
I have latest Eclipse/CDT/NDK/etc.
Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**
fadden: Thanks for the answer. This comment would have been too long so I put it here.
Yes, I use ${NDKROOT}/ndk-build.cmd to build the native part.

Yeah, I noticed cases when Eclipse would indicate errors so it wouldn't even let me start to build the app, but when I restart Eclipse without opening the file where the error was, it actually builds successfully. But when I open the file which it thinks has errors, it wouldn't let me start to build again. So it really looks like there's quite some inconsistency between errors indicated by Eclipse and actual errors (preventing building). Maybe I should just find a way to let it build regardless of indicated errors, though it could be annoying having errors in the project that should be just ignored, not knowing what are real and what are not so real errors... Or just add everything that is needed to include directories to keep Eclipse happy, so far it seems to be working, just wasn't sure if this was really the right way to do it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making Eclipse + CDT happy with Android is largely a matter of trial and error.  (Days or perhaps weeks have been irrevocably lost trying to get size_t to work right.)  Ultimately you should be building with the NDK toolchain, not Eclipse, so as long as Eclipse *seems* to be happy you're probably in good shape because ultimately it won't affect your binaries.

As you've noticed, some of the headers (like `stdarg.h`) are provided by gcc, not bionic, so it is necessary to dig around a bit.  I expect there's a define somewhere that equates `__va_list` to `va_list` if you have the right #defines set (maybe `__need___va_list`??).